# Expected sum of exponential variables until two of them sum to a threshold

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

In answering [finding Expected Value for a system with N events all having exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817387/), I somehow missed the fact that the OP wanted the expected value conditional on the number of events. Since I put quite a bit of effort into deriving the unconditional expected value, and this might conceivably be of interest for other purposes, I'm asking this question to post the result.

We have a sequence of random variables that are independently identically exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. We sum them until two consecutive values add up to at least $\tau$ (with the values that cause the termination included in the sum). What is the expected value of the sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply one-step analysis, we need to keep track of the value $X$ last added, that is, we need to set up an equation for $E[S\mid X=x]$, where $S$ is the expected sum of the terms yet to come.

The next value makes an expected contribution $\frac1\lambda$ to the sum. Then with density $\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda r}$ for $0\le r\le\tau-x$ we add another expected $E[S\mid X=r]$. Thus

$$
E[S\mid X=x]=\frac1\lambda+\int_0^{\tau-x}\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda r}E[S\mid X=r]\mathrm dr\;.
$$

Differentiating with respect to $x$ yields (with the prime denoting differentiation with respect to $x$)

$$
E'[S\mid X=x]=-\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda(\tau-x)}E[S\mid X=\tau-x]\;.
$$

After a lot of fiddling around with exponential trial functions, the solution of this equation is found to be

$$
E[S\mid X=x]=\frac1N\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\mu_+}}\mathrm e^{\mu_+\left(x-\frac\tau2\right)}-\frac1{\sqrt{\mu_-}}\mathrm e^{\mu_-\left(x-\frac\tau2\right)}\right)\;,
$$

where

$$
\mu_\pm=\frac\lambda2\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-4\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}}\right)
$$

and the normalisation factor $N$ is determined by the boundary condition $E[S\mid X=\tau]=\frac1\lambda$ to be

$$
N=\lambda\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\mu_+}}\mathrm e^{\mu_+\frac\tau2}-\frac1{\sqrt{\mu_-}}\mathrm e^{\mu_-\frac\tau2}\right)\;.
$$

Since we add a second term even if the first one is greater than $\tau$ (with probability $\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}$), the desired expected value $E[S]$ of the sum is given by

$$
E[S]=E[S\mid X=0]+\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}}\lambda\;.
$$

Substituting $x=0$ and simplifying leads to

$$
E[S]=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}}\lambda\left(\frac{\xi\mathrm e^{\frac{\lambda\tau}2}+2\sin\frac{\xi\lambda\tau}2}{\xi\cos\frac{\xi\lambda\tau}2-\sin\frac{\xi\lambda\tau}2}+1\right)\;,
$$

where $\xi=\sqrt{4\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}-1}$, in the case $\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}\lt4$, and

$$
E[S]=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}}\lambda\left(\frac{\zeta\mathrm e^{\frac{\lambda\tau}2}+2\sinh\frac{\zeta\lambda\tau}2}{\zeta\cosh\frac{\zeta\lambda\tau}2-\sinh\frac{\zeta\lambda\tau}2}+1\right)\;,
$$

where $\zeta=\sqrt{1-4\mathrm e^{-\lambda\tau}}$, in the case $\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}\gt4$. In the boundary case $\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}=4$, applying L'Hôpital to either expression yields

$$
E[S]=\frac1{4\lambda}\frac{3+\log2}{1-\log2}\;.
$$

Here's a plot of $\lambda E[S]$ as a function of $\lambda\tau$, with the boundary case $\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}=4$ halfway along the horizontal axis:

[image: plot of $\lambda E[S]$ as a function of $\lambda\tau$]

[Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/6459dd71e06fafa4d9a66defdde62df5) I used to draw the graph and to check the result by simulation.

Two limiting cases: For small $\lambda\tau$,

$$
E[S]=\frac1\lambda\left(2+\frac12(\lambda\tau)^2+O\left((\lambda\tau)^3\right)\right)\;,
$$

in agreement with the fact that we always add at least two terms and the probability for adding a third term is approximately $\frac12(\lambda\tau)^2$.

And for large $\lambda\tau$,

$$
E[S]=\frac1\lambda\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}}{\lambda\tau-1}+O(1)\right)\;,
$$

which should be compared to the estimate

$$
E[S]\approx\frac1\lambda\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{\lambda\tau}}{\lambda\tau+1}\right)
$$

that results from estimating the expected number of terms by the reciprocal of the probability of a given pair of terms terminating the process; the correlations between adjacent pairs lead to the actual result being slightly higher (with $-1$ instead of $+1$ in the denominator).

Here's a plot up to $\lambda\tau=6$ with these two approximations shown in green:

[image: graph with approximations]