# Expected sum of exponential variables respecting a threshold

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

This question continues the previously asked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818505/expected-sum-of-exponential-variables-until-two-of-them-sum-to-a-threshold) which is solved by @joriki.

As you can see in the figure, there is cahce which I refered as system in  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818505/expected-sum-of-exponential-variables-until-two-of-them-sum-to-a-threshold). Data item $i$ is requested by users. The request arrivals have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ as the mean of distribution. Item $i$ gets/remains stored in the cache if and only if the time period between $l-1^{th}$ and $l+1^{th}$ requests for it, depicted by $t_l$ in the figure, is less than $\tau$ (i.e. $t_l<\tau$ for $1\le l < n$). Item $i$ is evicted from the cache as soon as $t_n>\tau$. The time period between the beginning of $t_1$ and end of $t_n$ is depicted by $T_i^1$. To calculate $T_i^1$, we can say that we have a sequence of random variables that are independently identically exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. We sum them until two consecutive values add up to at least $\tau$ (with the values that causes item $i$'s eviction from the cache). $E[T_i^1]$ is calculated by @joriki as an answer to  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818505/expected-sum-of-exponential-variables-until-two-of-them-sum-to-a-threshold).

next requests for item $i$ does not lead to storing it in the cache as long as $t_l > \tau$ for $n < l < m$. Item $i$ is actually gets stored again in cache as soon as $t_m<\tau$. To get the expected value of time period between the beginning of $t_n$ and end of $t_m$, depicted by $T_i^2$ (as shown in the figure), we can say that we have a sequence of random variables that are independently identically exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. We sum them until two consecutive values add up to up to $\tau$ (with the values that causes item $i$ to return to the cache). $T_i^3$, which is the mean time required for item $i$ to get cached back after its eviction, could be easily calculated as follows: $E[T_i^3] = E[T_i^2] - E[t_n] = E[T_i^2] -\frac{2}{\lambda}$

What I am looking for is $E[T_i^2]$ as well as $E[T_i^{total}]$.

[image]

Comment: There seem to be two conflicting descriptions here of what you want. In the first description, $T$ and $T'$ are measured in the same process, as shown in the diagram, where $t_1'$ starts off with the longer segment that ended $T$ by causing $t_n$ to exceed $\tau$; whereas in the second description, you define $T'$ to be summed from scratch, with $t_1'$ starting out without bias. Which one is it? Also, have you tried applying the approach I used for the other question?

Comment: @joriki Well, you are right about the conflicting descriptions. I should say what you see in the diagram is an accurate definition of $T^{\prime}$.
What I am actually looking for is the expected value of time between two misses over $T^{total}$. In the diagram, $T$ is the first time interval between two misses. Then, the time interval between each pair of black squares is another time interval between two misses. To this end, my understanding if correct, is that we need to find $T$, $T^{\prime}$ and $T^{total}$.

Comment: @joriki I also tried hard to understand your solution for the other question, for which I really appreciate your answer. However, I could not get it since I don't have very good math background.

Comment: @joriki what if we assume $t_1^{\prime}$ is independent of $t_n, $for the sake of simplicity? in other words, we define $T^{\prime}$ as it is defined in the question (the text not the diagram). Does it make the question simpler?

Comment: @joriki I modified the question. I hope it makes sense now.